# PYTHON2: how to use a while loop and user input to count to a certain number that the user inputs?

Tags: python, while-loop, python-2.x

So i have this code sprint assignment for school where i have the user input a certain number and then the computer program will count to that number. but i have no idea how to do that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Wbjt.png). so i will put two pictures down and if anyone wants to help that would be very appreciated! (look at the bottom of the second picture.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhIxd.png)

Comment: Did you write the code that says `tray = 1; while tray < 11: tray += 1` and `twelve = 12; while twelve < 24: twelve += 3`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? It has been EOL for a while.

Comment: Screenshot of code isn't helpful. Question is basically asking the community to do the authors homework.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use the while loop in this way

```
user_input = int(raw_input("enter a number: "))
x = 0

while x<user_input:
    print x
    x+=1
```

Comment: It's python 2, use `raw_input()`.

Comment: `<` should be `<=`